# SFTP "Could not connect to server error"

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, ftp

I'm having problems connecting to my server via SFTP. I can SSH in to the system perfectly fine, but for some odd reason, i'm not able to SFTP (which I used to be able to).

I have cleared ALL my iptables rules `iptables -F` still no access. I have removed the sub system (to allow FULL access) still no access. I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. Thus is therefore making a solution impossible.

**Update**

Subsystem configuration section from http://pastebin.com/eZwZ5Z7w

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp sftp-server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removal of the sftp subsystem is what would disable sftp. Try adding the entry again. If it still doesn't work after restarting the ssh service, update the question with your sshd config.

**Update**

The config you provided doesn't give the full path, try using the commented version.

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

For example, my config has

```
# grep sftp /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

and if I look for the file via locate, it confirm that it is only located there.

```
# locate sftp-server
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
/usr/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8.gz
```

Comment: I did re-enable them and restart ssh, the config is... http://pastebin.com/eZwZ5Z7w

Comment: Damn it - Why did I comment out the working line? Thanks for your response it's working perfectly fine now (I shall wear the derp hat).

Answer (score 2):

This probably will not help the original poster, but I ran into another cause that results in the same symptoms.

The symptoms:  When I `sftp -v <user>@<host>`, the connection blocks after printing:

```
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
```

The cause: In order to bypass the system default shell configuration, I have put the following line at the top of `~/.bashrc`:

```
exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM bash --noprofile --rcfile ~/.bash2
```

Even simply `exec bash` causes the same problem.  I guess this makes sense - the sourcing of `~/.bashrc` never returns - instead a new instance of bash is exec'ed and replaces the old one.

It is perhaps surprising that the ssh server needs to source the shell config files before running `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`.

Update:  See also this related entry in the OpenSSH FAQ:
http://openssh.com/faq.html#2.9
(The entry titled: "sftp/scp fails at connection, but ssh is OK.")